# Me apare un error al intentar entrar datos en una tabla en SQL

Tags: sql

Me aparece este error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Orders_Customers". The conflict occurred in database "NORTHWND",
>   table "dbo.Customers", column 'CustomerID'.

Cuando trato de insertar datos a la tabla

```
insert into Orders (OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipVia,
Freight,ShipName,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry)

 values

(11078,'RALLO',3,'1998-05-06','1998-06-03',NULL,2,19.35,'Bon bistro','Tijuana','Mexico','NM',02589,'Mexico'),

(11079,'OLLAR',NULL,'1998-05-06','1998-06-03',NULL,3,35.19,'Simons Bon','Caracas','Venezuela',NULL,98520,'Venezuela');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Orders  On;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y estas cumpliendo la regla que te marca el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas teniendo problemas por que estas insertando '`RALLO`' y '`OLLAR`' en el CustomerID, y eso te esta generando un problema de llave foránea por que no existe `Id` con esos datos en la tabla `Customers`.

No conozco la estructura de tu base de datos se me hace muy extraño que coloque como llave foránea un campo `varchar`.

Por buenas prácticas todas tus llaves foráneas deberían ser numéricas.